# Invalid date django form validation

Tags: python, django, forms, date

I am **learning** Django and building a **CRUD** but I'm getting an error in my **form validation**.

This is the form that ** I created**

```
class addSignForm(forms.ModelForm):
active = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

class Meta:
    model = signs
    fields = ("id", "active", "action", "date", "expiration_date", "add_by", "user_sign")
    widgets = {
        'date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
    }
```

This is the date that I am **receiving from the request** **(also tried format: '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M'

```
'2000-04-16T18:57'
```

And when I try to:

```
if (form.is_valid()):
```

says that it is an invalid form and that I typed an **invalid date**

```
<li>Enter a valid date/time.</li></ul>
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

`"2000-04-16T18:57"` is not `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M` format but `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M` format. Check list date formatters here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 1):

Your widget format just show for client, not for Form.So you can try add a method named clean_date(self) to replace 'T' with whitespace then return it.
or add your format into DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS list of settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up managing to solve the problem, however I did not like the solution because it does not seem the most right ... however I will share it here in case people experience the same problem :)

What i did was:

create a copy of my GET so it becomes mutable

```
getCopy = request.GET.copy()
```

after that i converted the DATE that was comming from GET

```
ts = time.strptime(request.GET['date'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
getCopy['date'] = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", ts)
```

and when i call my *form.is_valid* instead of passing request.GET, i pass my mutable copy of GET with my formatted date :)